# Chrome thinks my JavaScript is Mandarin

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, typescript

When I compile and run my typescript and load the page in google chrome, google chrome thinks my javascript is mandarin.

Here's my .ts file:

```
class Student {
fullName: string;
constructor(public firstName, public middleInitial, public lastName) {
    this.fullName = firstName + " " + middleInitial + " " + lastName;
}
}


interface Person {
firstName: string;
lastName: string;
}


function greeter(person: Person) {
return "Hello, " + person.firstName + person.lastName;
}

var user = new Student("Mike", "A", "Harv");

document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
```

Here's my .js file:

```
var Student = (function () {
function Student(firstName, middleInitial, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.fullName = firstName + " " + middleInitial + " " + lastName;
}
return Student;
}());
function greeter(person) {
return "Hello, " + person.firstName + person.lastName;
}
var user = new Student("Mike", "A", "Harv");
document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
```

Here's my .html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>TypeScript Greeter</title></head>
<body>
    <script src="greeter.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Edit: The encoding on my .js file is UTF-8

[image]

Hex-dump of my js file.

[image]

Comment: You might have some non-visible Unicode characters in there.

Comment: Your file is stored in a different character set (encoding) than it is served with. More: [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Completely separate from your question, I'm a bit surprised your TS code compiles, considering `Student` does not implement `Person`, and yet you are passing it to `greeter`...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan TypeScript interfaces (unlike other languages) are duck interfaces. In TypeScript, Student implements Person.

Comment: @TamasHegedus, I'm well versed in TypeScript, and the OP included their TypeScript in the question. Where in *that* TypeScript does `Student` implement `Person`?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Sorry, there must be a problem with my English. I meant that the script OP included is correctly typed and compiles well. You don't have to explicitly `implement` an interface, as long as your class has the right properties. For example if student didn't have firstName it would be a compile time error to call `greeter(user)`. If it explicitly implemented Person, a compile time error would be shown on the Student class.

Comment: Did you try factory reset for chrome. It helped me once. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en

Comment: @Tamas Oh, got it. Weird, I never noticed that. I knew you could provide anonymous objects which had the same properties as an interface, but hadn't made the mental leap to actual classes that shared the same properties. Makes sense now that I think about it. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: The encoding in my js file is utf-8. Why would chrome treat this as some other encoding?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey How do you serve your files? Its possible that it has the wrong http content-encoding header. Maybe you opened it with VisualStudio and saved it with BOM, and the server you use cant recognize the BOM so makes a random guess about the encoding.

Comment: @TamasHegedus I opened the html file locally, so no headers were set.

Comment: What's in the geeter.js file? I feel like its stored gzipped on the filesystem.

Comment: @TamasHegedus $cat greeter.js is just my javascript file.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey And hexdump? What does hexdump say? What are the first 10 bytes?

Comment: @TamasHegedus I added a picture of the hex dump to the question.

Comment: This is getting interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mandarin letters you see will appear if you decode the utf-8 (without bom) encoded greeter.js file as UCS2-LE. I tried to convince Chrome to decode the utf8 encoded file as ucs2le, but I didnt managed to. It looks every program including chrome, will only use UCS2-LE if the right BOM is present at the beginning of the file. The following bytes `FF FE 76 61 72 20 53 74 ...` (These bytes are the same as in your hexdump, with `FF FE prepended`)  will be decoded to:

[image]

These are the same characters as on your screenshot.

Given all this, I am pretty sure that your greeter.js files encoding is broken, it has the UCS2 bom `FF FE`, and the utf8 encoded bytes of the javascript are appended.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by saving my js file with encoding UTF-8 with BOM.

Comment: What language setting do you use in chrome? It might be affected by the default language.

Comment: @TamasHegedus I'm using English (US)